# How do I fill rows with multiple values using Excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report that's received as a .txt file. I recorded a macro to open the file as space delimited. The report has multiple pages and contains the employee name at the top of each page. I want to add a step to my initial macro that will copy their name for each day they had sales. The number of days for each associate can vary each week so I need to be able to identify a range for the number of days they have on the report and copy their name for each row.

In the example I need Johns name to be copied on each row for dates 4/1 through 4/5, Debbie's name for the days she had sales, Mary for the days she had sales.

How can I accomplish this?

[image: Sales Report]

Comment: You can use a filter, write a formula, and while doing this record a macro, then you'll have a good starting point…

Comment: more specifically...what's the vba code to perform this function please...

Comment: How is your data going to be separated for each associate. In your example, would it be a space between each associate? Also, are you assuming that the second column will always contain the Sale stats?

Comment: In my example, the date and sales dollars will always appear in columns A and B. The associate name will always appear in column E. I've found other scripts that will remove the rows I don't need but before running those scripts, I need to fill in the each associates name next their sales dates and dollars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below should help you. the code below assumes that you filled the name of the person always in column e, row (start of dates - 1). You need to change the sheet index or name it "Your_sheet_Name" and if needed change to for i = 2 to ..."1000" -> sometimes ells.

```
Sub Nieuws()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        For i = 2 To .Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
        startpoint = 0
        endpoint = 0

            If .Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then
                counter = counter + 1
                If counter > 20 Then Exit Sub
            End If

            If .Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then
                startpoint = i
                'assuming that you only have 14 max rows
                For j = i To i + 14
                    If .Range("A" & j).Value = "" Then
                        endpoint = j - 1
                        GoTo filldata
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
filldata:
            If startpoint > 0 And endpoint > 0 Then
                For k = startpoint + 1 To endpoint
                    .Range("D" & k).Value = .Range("E" & startpoint - 1)
                Next k

                i = endpoint + 1
                counter = 0
            End If

         Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sélect the texte to convert in table
Then go to table tools, disposition, clic convert to text
and in the zone Convert to text, nder Sépareate the text , clic on the chacter that defines the limit of an argument for a colon

Answer (score 0):

modify and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long, y As Long
    Dim strName As String

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change if needed

            Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 3 To Lastrow

                If .Range("E" & i).Value <> "" Then

                    strName = .Range("E" & i).Value

                    y = i + 1

                    Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(y, "A").Value)

                        If IsDate(.Cells(y, "A").Value) Then
                            .Cells(y, "C").Value = strName
                        End If

                        y = y + 1

                    Loop

                End If

            Next i

        End With

    End Sub
```